# fetching and separating single column data from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display only user selected pages in dashboard

I have two columns in database like this

```
create table users(userid varchar(50), scripts varchar(100))
```

in `userid column` i will have the logged in user name and in `scripts column`, names of the pages which they want to display it in dashboard in comma separated format. **ex: total, cust_orders,...**

I want to fetch page name from scripts column separately like `total.php, cust_orders.php...`
i tried doing like this

```
$sql = "select scripts from users where userid = '".$_SESSION['UserID']."' ";

$result = DB_query($sql,$db);
$myrow = DB_fetch_array($result);


foreach ($myrow as $res)
    {

        $array123[] = $res;
        $var123 = $array123[0];
        $var222 = $array123[1];

    }
```

but it wont work as the pages can be from 1 to 8, can somebody please help me in this?

**EDITED**

I have done like this

```
$result = DB_query($sql,$db);
$myrow = DB_fetch_array($result);

$arr= $myrow['scripts'];

$arr1 = explode(',', $myrow['scripts']);
print_r ($arr1);
```

and it worked, it displays like this

```
Array ( [0] => total_dashboard [1] => customer_orders [2] => unpaid_invoice [3] => lat
```

but dynamically how can i separate it and i have to add `.php` to this ...

Comment: Why not normalize your schema?

Comment: If the scripts are a comma separated list then, once your data is back in php then you can use arr = explode(',', $myrows['scripts'] );

Comment: @jeff: i tried it, but it didn't work

Comment: @jeff i have edited my post above, plz have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "select scripts from users where userid = '".$_SESSION['UserID']."' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$db);
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $arr=explode(',',$myrow["scripts"]);//this will strip the , separated values in an array 
    //now you can fetch the scripts from database
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but how can i add .php for each page. for that i have to separate na.. that i dont get

Comment: @ user2669924-: please elaborate what you don't get

Comment: @user2669924-:  you must have the php pages relating to all these scripts, just include them in the dashboard with php include

Comment: i have another table with php page names , but how to include it? as i need to display all selected pages in dashboard

Comment: I mean in this, how i can show only user selected pages in dashboard?

Comment: use $arr to fetch data from another table ,simple

Comment: do you have the pages like if you have the entry in scripts column as hello, hten do you have the page hello.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP - explode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php) like:

```
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
    // $myrow->scripts = "text1.php,text2.php,text3.php";
    $scripts = explode(',', $myrow->scripts);
}
```

So `$scripts` will then contain each PHP-Page/Skript as own position in the array.

```
$scripts[0] = "text1.php";
$scripts[1] = "text2.php";
$scripts[2] = "text3.php";
```

Comment: but if the user selects more that 3 pages, then how it works? it should happen dynamically na , that i am not getting

Comment: `$scripts` is dynamically. Not necessary if he selected 3, 5 or 0 pages.